# SQL Server - I can connect using shared memory on the server machine but not when I force TCP, any ideas why?

Tags: sql-server, tcp, ssms

I have two PCs running Win10. I am having difficulty connecting to SQL Server from the client, so I followed some basic steps to see where everything falls over.

Client can ping the servers IP address and the device name with OK replies.

SQL Server Management Studio can connect to the server when run on the server PC, won't connect when run from the client.

SQL Server Management Studio can connect, I assume using Shared Memory as it is local, but forcing TCP by entering TCP: before the instance name causes the connect error when tried on the server PC - cannot find server not accessible etc etc.

SQL Server Configuration Mgr: the TCP protocol is enabled, IPALL has a setting 'TCP Port - 49172' and the server is running.  Also has a TCP Dynamic port open if that's any help.

Any idea's what to check next, I know its the TCP somewhere but have run out of ideas (even put rules in the firewall to allow SQL Server Express etc)

Many thanks

Guy

Comment: Having the actual error code and message would be good.  Also, check your firewall on the server for Port 1433. For more details on configuring the firewall for nonassigned port numbers (such as named instances and SQL Server Express), [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15) is a good resource.

Comment: Try turning off your firewall on the serving machine not a couple minutes and retesting if it works, the it a firewall issue, and if not.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your very quick responses. I tested the firewall and found the problem.  Disabling the firewalls allowed the server based SQL Management Studio to work with TCP/IP and also allowed the client machine to link in.  I found the problem in the Inbound rules that I had created, I had set the rules for just Private network and Win10 had decided that the connection was Public.  Amended the rules and it all works fine.  Again many many thanks.